# Unsupported Operand int and str?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add all the elements in a list but it keeps popping up with unsupported operand for int and string any idea?

```
total_years = 0
for i in range(len(str(years_list))):
    total_years += str(years_list[i])
print(years_total)
```

if I use int it comes up with IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total_years` is an integer and `str(years_list[i])` is a string. You can't add a string to an integer.

When you use `int` instead, you get IndexError because you're iterating way past the end of `years_list`. The string representation of a list is typically much longer than the list's actual length. Ex. `[1,2,3]` has a length of 3, but `str([1,2,3])` has a length of 9 because it counts the commas and brackets and spaces. Maybe you meant to do `for i in range(len(years_list))`.

You don't need any of this type-changing stuff anyway. If you want to add all the elements of a list, use `sum`.

```
total_years = sum(years_list)
```